# How to represent invisible name-value pair data associated with HTML table row?

Tags: html, html-table, metadata, frameset

**Background**

I am presenting data using a HTML frameset.  The left-side frame is a navigation tree-table constructed as an HTML table.  Only minimal data is shown in this frame because I want to use the right-side "details" frame to give the user more details when he selects one of the navigation table rows.

```
+----------------------------+
|          |                 |
| tree     |   "details"     |
| table    | pertaining to   |
| nav.     |   selected      |
|          |     row         |
|=selected=|                 |
|          |                 |
|          |                 |
|          |                 |
+----------------------------+
```

Think of this like a directory browser where you can see filesize, type, modification date, etc. on the right when you select an item in the left-hand tree.

Obtaining item details server-side is a sequential task, i.e. to get details on the nth item, the server has to work through all n-1 preceding items.  For this reason, I think the most straightforward way to present the detailed data to the user is to have the server embed all detailed information within the navigation table rows and have a script generate the details page in a right-hand frame.

**Question**

How should I represent the detailed data within the navigation table HTML?  Should I make up my own element tagnames?  Should I use extra columns that are not displayed?  Or something else?  The data is typically name-value pairs - both name and value can be text.  Each element may have a different set of data pairs.  Is there a standard way to represent user data within an (X)HTML document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NEVER, EVER EVER EVER EVER EVER EVER mix data and display.  I also think you can easily get around the iterating over n elements to get the data you require.  Here is how you do it.

Create a model (your data storage) in the javascript.

```
var data = [
   {
      title: "item 1",
      foo: "bar",
      baz: 10
   },
   {
      title: "item 2",
      foo: "bazbar",
      baz: 20
   }
];
```

Then, using Javascript, you could use the above data to create the following table on the left

```
<table>
   <tr><td><a href="#" onclick="showDetails(0);return false;">item 1</a></td></tr>
   <tr><td><a href="#" onclick="showDetails(1);return false;">item 2</a></td></tr>
</table>
```

So then you would have your show details function

```
function showDetails(index){
   var currentData = data[index];
   /* Do something with data */
}
```

I have created a working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/w2EQy/2/).  There is an error in that code that says showDetails is not defined, but that is due to a jsfiddle issue, the code will work if put into a HTML page.  ALSO, be sure to use the strict doctype at the top (to avoid cross browser quirsk).

Might I also suggest, that you look at [YUI 2's layout manager](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/layout/) instead of using a frameset.  Framesets require multiple pages with javascript snaked throughout and can be a maintenance nightmare down the road.

Comment: Nice - so I guess this means I will be delivering very little coded HTML, a bit of CSS, a fair amount of Javascript code and a lot of data in Javascript format.

Comment: In my answer, yes, but I made my answer assuming you were not using a serverside technology.  If you were using php, asp.net or j2ee my answer might have been a bit different.  The only problem with my answer is it is not google spider friendly, but if you do not intend people to search for this page in Google, there shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I am using C++ server-side as the data is generated through a highly-optimized computationally intensive process.  Hence why random access after generation is costly.  It's private data and not needed for search.

Comment: I also should have said I want to support progressive streaming - navigation table populates as server generates it (might take 10 seconds). So might not use the pure JS approach.

Comment: How many records are you going to have on the left hand side?  Using setTimeout you can have javascript progressively build the list a few chunks at a time, or, you can make use of the YUI paginator, which would be preferable to a LARGE scroll bar along the side.  I think you are underestimating the speed of javascript.

Comment: Perhaps up to around 1000 items.  I'm not underestimating JS itself, I'm being realistic about my ability to learn enough JS quickly enough!

Comment: Javascript is not that hard, I have had people get up to speed on it (enough to be productive) in about a week.  Let me update my answer to it has more detail on how to accomplish this.

Comment: I added a link to jsfiddle which has a working example of the code.  Again, there is a small error, but that is because of jsfiddle.  If you put the code into a browser, it should work fine.